# Adding a custom header to HTTP request using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers

I am a novice to angular.js, and I am trying to add some headers to a request:

```
   var config = {headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==',
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        }
    };

   $http.get('https://www.example.com/ApplicationData.svc/Malls(1)/Retailers', config).success(successCallback).error(errorCallback);
```

I've looked at all the documentation, and this seems to me like it should be correct.

When I use a local file for the URL in the `$http.get`, I see the following HTTP request on the network tab in Chrome:

```
GET /app/data/offers.json HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
If-None-Match: "0f0abc9026855b5938797878a03e6889"
Authorization: Basic Y2hhZHN0b25lbWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
If-Modified-Since: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 15:58:55 GMT
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22
X-Testing: Testing
Referer: http://www.example.com/app/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

As you can see, both of the headers were added correctly. But when I change the URL to the one shown in the `$http.get` above (except using the real address, not example.com), then I get:

```
OPTIONS /ApplicationData.svc/Malls(1) HTTP/1.1
Host: www.datahost.net
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://mpon.site44.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, origin, x-requested-with, authorization, x-testing
Accept: */*
Referer: http://mpon.site44.com/app/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

The only difference in code between these two is one is for the first the URL is a local file, and for the second the URL is a remote server. If you look at the second Request header, there is no Authentication header, and the `Accept` appears to be using a default instead of the one specified. Also, the first line now says `OPTIONS` instead of `GET` (although `Access-Control-Request-Method` is `GET`).

Any idea what is wrong with the above code, or how to get the additional headers included using when not using a local file as a data source?

Comment: This looks like a CORS issue - take a read through this discussion for some background: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/CSBMY6oXfqs

Comment: It was indeed a CORS issue. The server was not configured to return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: header. If you want to write up an answer with your comment and a little bit of detail on CORS, I'll accept your answer. The answer below from Dmitry Evseev and edited by you was close, but not really the actual problem.

Comment: Chrome is preflighting the request to look for CORS headers if the request is cross domain. Check my answer.

Answer (score 66):

I took what you had, and added another `X-Testing` header

```
var config = {headers:  {
        'Authorization': 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==',
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        "X-Testing" : "testing"
    }
};

$http.get("/test", config);
```

And in the Chrome network tab, I see them being sent.

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22
Authorization: Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==
X-Testing: testing
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Are you not seeing them from the browser, or on the server?  Try the browser tooling or a debug proxy and see what is being sent out.

Comment: I don't have access to the server, and on the browser I am using Firefox, but I'm seeing the headers I added to the original question above. I don't see where you can view the headers on the resource tab in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I added an edit to your answer that was meant to go in my original question.

Comment: I meant the network tab of the developer tools, not resources - updates answer

Comment: I added more information to the question. It looks like the headers are added in one case, but not another.

Answer (score 21):

Basic authentication using HTTP POST method:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/API/authenticate',
    data: 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&email=' + email,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "X-Login-Ajax-call": 'true'
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    if (response.data == 'ok') {
        // success
    } else {
        // failed
    }
});
```

...and GET method call with header:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/books',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "X-Login-Ajax-call": 'true'
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    if (response.data == 'ok') {
        // success
    } else {
        // failed
    }
});
```

Comment: The best answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to add your custom headers to ALL requests, you can change the defaults on $httpProvider to always add this header…

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = { 
        'Authorization': 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==',
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
      };
}]);
```

Comment: ALL but OPTIONS requests that is

Comment: nice example. can this be used to cache token for redirecting pages?

Answer (score 7):

my suggestion will be add a function call settings like this
inside the function check the header which is appropriate for it. I am sure it will definitely work. it is perfectly working for me.

```
function getSettings(requestData) {
    return {
        url: requestData.url,
        dataType: requestData.dataType || "json",
        data: requestData.data || {},
        headers: requestData.headers || {
            "accept": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + requestData.token
        },
        async: requestData.async || "false",
        cache: requestData.cache || "false",
        success: requestData.success || {},
        error: requestData.error || {},
        complete: requestData.complete || {},
        fail: requestData.fail || {}
    };
}
```

then call your data like this

```
    var requestData = {
        url: 'API end point',
        data: Your Request Data,
        token: Your Token
    };

    var settings = getSettings(requestData);
    settings.method = "POST"; //("Your request type")
    return $http(settings);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you see for OPTIONS request is fine. Authorisation headers are not exposed in it.

But in order for basic auth to work you need to add: `withCredentials = true;` to your `var config`.

From the AngularJS [$http documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http):

> **withCredentials** - `{boolean}` - whether to to set the `withCredentials`
>   flag on the XHR object. See [requests with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#section_5) for more
>   information.

Answer (score 1):

And what's the answer from the server? It should reply a 204 and then really send the GET you are requesting.

In the OPTIONS the client is checking if the server allows CORS requests. If it gives you something different than a 204 then you should configure your server to send the correct Allow-Origin headers.

The way you are adding headers is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is preflighting the request to look for CORS headers. If the request is acceptable, it will then send the real request. If you're doing this cross-domain, you will simply have to deal with it or else find a way to make the request non-cross-domain. This is by design.

> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first
>   send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the
>   other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe
>   to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may
>   have implications to user data. In particular, a request is
>   preflighted if:
>
> It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST. Also, if POST is used to
>   send request data with a Content-Type other than
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain,
>   e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using
>   application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted. It sets
>   custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header such as
>   X-PINGOTHER)

Ref: [AJAX in Chrome sending OPTIONS instead of GET/POST/PUT/DELETE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783079/ajax-in-chrome-sending-options-instead-of-get-post-put-delete)

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding a header which server does not allow.

eg - your server is set up CORS to allow these headers only (accept,cache-control,pragma,content-type,origin)

and in your http request you are adding like this

```
 headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'x-testing': 'testingValue'
    }
```

then the Server will reject this request since (Authorization and x-testing) are not allowed.

This is server side configuration.

And there is nothing to do with HTTP Options, it is just a preflight to server which is from different domain to check if server will allow actual call or not.

Answer (score -9):

For me the following explanatory snippet worked. Perhaps you shouldn't use `'` for header name?

```
{
   headers: { 
      Authorization: "Basic " + getAuthDigest(), 
      Accept: "text/plain" 
   }
}
```

I'm using `$http.ajax()`, though I wouldn't expect that to be a game changer.