# Angular $http.get to same host but different port fails with no meaningful error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running an Angular script that performs an $http.get(...) on a REST resource located at `http://localhost:7700`, but it's executing from a page served at `http://localhost:4400`. I'm not certain if this is the problem, but it results in the error() callback firing, with a status of 0, and nothing in the data parameter. Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) is protocol + host + port

You would need to enable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) support to allow this situation

Comment: for more info on how, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598917/adding-a-custom-header-to-http-request-using-angular-js