# jQuery not sending Authorization header

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

For some reason, this code is not sending the Authorization header. Why is that? Are there alternatives?

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(q),
      url: "https://elasticsearchinstance" + "/index/_search",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false, 
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("username:password")
      },
      success: searchCallback
    });

401 Unauthorized
```

If I manually edit the request in Fiddler to add the Authorization header, I get HTTP 200.

Edit - including this also does not help:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization",  "Basic " +btoa("username:password")); 
},
```

Edit - username and password also have no effect:

```
username: "username",
password: "password"
```

Comment: I think my issues is related to this browser behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783079/ajax-in-chrome-sending-options-instead-of-get-post-put-delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - turns out my ElasticSearch instance had CORS disabled. As I understand it, Chrome insists on sending an OPTIONS request to see if cross-domain POST is allowed before sending the POST itself in order to protect the security of the browser user.

By manually modifying the request and adding the Authorization header in Fiddler, I was able to skip that. (Due to the browser's insistence on OPTIONS, no website would arbitrarily have the ability to do that via javascript, which is why I couldn't get the header added).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [username and password](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of headers?

Comment: I just tried that as well, but it also doesn't have any effect. I've tried with both jQuery 1.11.2 and 2.1.3. Very confusing...