# RestApi call using iron-ajax throwing error

Tags: ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am making a RestApi call from localhost and i got the below error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api-address/v1/registeruser.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource.Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8887' is therefore not allowed  access. 
The response had HTTP status code 502.
```

then i tried fixing this and added CORS extention to chrome which i got from SO.
after adding the extention I again got the below error

```
POST https://api-address/v1/registeruser 502 (Proxy Error)
```

how to fix this issue?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/40153999/6277151

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome this may be related to the fact that it is preflighting ajax requests by sending OPTIONS before GET/POST/PUT/DELETE as discussed here:

[AJAX in Chrome sending OPTIONS instead of GET/POST/PUT/DELETE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783079/ajax-in-chrome-sending-options-instead-of-get-post-put-delete)

I suggest making sure that your REST server is capable of responding to OPTIONS request.