# Two calls in network tab with different type

Tags: ajax, sitecore

Am facing an issue, where two calls are getting registered in network tab (PFA) [image]
These two calls have same request and responses. 
Actually there is one call only made from client side. Need to understand why this second call getting registered.
FYI : This is sitecore based project. `window.location.href` is used in JS side.

Please provide insights for this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever a cross-origin request is made, two requests are send, instead of one by chrome:
1. The first one is option type. It checks whether the origin is allowed or not.
2. The second one is your actual request.

For more information, have a look on answers here: [AJAX in Chrome sending OPTIONS instead of GET/POST/PUT/DELETE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783079/ajax-in-chrome-sending-options-instead-of-get-post-put-delete)

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, it seems that there are 2 different Initiators calling the same resource. You have 1 AJAX call (xhr) and the other one is Document which might be in the page itself or another JS.