# Not able to set custom header in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I am making a http get call and want to set some custom property in header but I am not able to see these properties at my back end even not visible in http request. Here is code used by me

```
app.controller("BranchController", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope){
    var req = {
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://192.168.3.239:8082/build-api/v1.1/builds/getbranch',
        headers: {
            "username": "abcd",
            "password" : "hhhh@@@@######"
        }
    }
    $http(req).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.branchs = data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('Api call failed', status)
    });
  });
```

here is the http request headers

```
OPTIONS /build-api/v1.1/builds/getbranch HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.3.239:8082
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: password, username
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:63342
Referer: http://localhost:63342/Build_Web/BranchList.html?_ijt=u6e7vvngu1n5o4a1doc1jig2g4
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Possible answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598917/adding-a-custom-header-to-http-request-using-angular-js

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double quotes in your headers object

Comment: Check in your config object I can see them there `config.headers.username`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are looking at the OPTIONS preflight request instead of the actual GET request. In your case I guess that the host "192.168.3.239:8082" is not the same as the one where your web application is served from. This causes the browser to issue a CORS OPTIONS preflight before making the actual GET request. There your custom headers are wrapped in the [Access-Control-Request-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers) header, without the actual values. The scenarios for a browser to issue an OPTIONS preflight are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it).

Make sure to enable CORS so you can inspect the actual GET request, there you will find your custom headers along with the values.