# Angular5 Creating custom headers

Tags: javascript, angular, http, post, http-headers

I have this fragment of code (simplified), I try to send a custom header "foo-custom" using http.post, but the request in the browser is sent as a 200 OPTIONS. What is it due?

Import

```
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

App

```
const myheaders = new Headers();
myheaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
myheaders.append('foo-custom', 'var');

const options = new RequestOptions({headers: myheaders});

this.http.post(
  this._url+'search', {}, options
).subscribe(data => {
  console.log("CORRECT!");
  console.log(data);
}, error => {
  console.log("ERROR!");
  console.log(error);    
});
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: **[Solution]**

When there are custom-headers custom headers, they must be enabled explicitly in the CROS configuration of the Spring-boot API

As a guide in the Spring-boot configuration, something like:
`corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("authorization");
corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("other"); `

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a preflighted request, can you check [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7445#issuecomment-192779586)

Possible [duplicated thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598917/adding-a-custom-header-to-http-request-using-angular-js)?